# Suppress any warnings about "unused" variables in Java

Tags: java, warnings

For some places in my code, I want to have variables that are not sensitive to *unused warnings* (compiling warn in Eclipse).

So I add annotation *@SuppressWarnings("unused")*. But after I decided to use that variable and I get a warn *Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unused")*. 
And I can't disable this warnings in the whole project because I need them in other parts.

How can I make one variable with no warnings in *unused* or *used* cases?

Comment: If it's your code anyways, why don't you just add and remove the suppress annotations as needed? After all the IDE should warn you about unused variables and the suppress annotations are the way to tell it to ignore that fact. And of course once you use the variable you remove that to prevent further errors. Additionally, having unused variables you don't need isn't adviceable anyways. There are situations in which you need them (e.g. when implementing some interface and not needing all parameters) but those should be rare and well thought.

Comment: @Thomas I was under the impression that parameters required to implement an interface weren't flagged as unused.

Comment: @AndyTurner In Eclipse, there is a checkbox "Ignore in overriding and implementing methods", so its configurable

Comment: @AndreasFester ah, I must have switched it on and forgotten about it :)

Comment: If you have at least Java 22 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78210982/6301562